# Net Outward Flux

Tags: calculus

I have what seems to be a simple problem, but my answer is not matching the book's.

Find the net outward flux of the vector field $F$ across the boundary $D$.

$F = (x^2, -y^2, z^2)$

$D$ is the region in the first octant between the planes $z = 4 - x - y$ and $z = 2 - x - y$.

I've computed the divergence of $F$ to be $2x - 2y + 2z$ and have taken the triple integral over the region with limits of integration from $z = 2 - x - y$ to $z = 4 - x - y$; $y = 0$ to $y = 4 - x$; and $x = 0$ to $x = 4$.  I obtain $\frac{32}3$ as my answer; but the book says it should be $20$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your triple integral isn't right. Try a 2D analogue: Consider the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x+y=2$ and $x+y=4$.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful.  $z$ should only range from $2-x-y$ to $4-x-y$ in the region $0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y\le 2-x$.  Remember, we want to stay in the first octant.  You will have to to do separate integrals.  See if you can visualize the regions described by the following three integrals.  They should sum up to $D$.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_{2-x-y}^{4-x-y}(2x-2y+2z)dV&=\frac{40}{3}\\\int_0^2\int_{2-x}^{4-x}\int_{0}^{4-x-y}(2x-2y+2z)dV&=0\\\int_2^4\int_0^{4-x}\int_{0}^{4-x-y}(2x-2y+2z)dV&=\frac{20}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: Now that makes more sense!  I was staring at your last answer for some time before I saw that you changed it.  This works.  Also, I think it would be easier to subtract the inner region, right?

Comment: @HectorRocker: Yes, I realized I too had not been careful and had to edit my previous answer.  Also, you're right to say that subtracting would be easier.